# Crop tool with high resolution

Tags: image-editor

I am now using Shutter in Ubuntu 13.10 for crop different selections and to select windows, but the problem is that the resolution is very low after I check it saving in all formats. Please tell me software, that I can save crop selections and images in high resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snapshot tools record the desktop at its running resolution. If you need a higher resolution picture then you will need to increase your screen resolution. If you have a small screen, consider using a virtual machine (as its virtual screen can be larger than your host monitor).

## Steps:

Step #1:

Click on the "cog" in the top right corner of your screen, and choose "system settings".

[image: step_1]

Step #2:

Click on "displays".

[image: step_2]

Step #3
Use the resolution options to pick a higher resolution (if available), and then click "apply".

[image: step_3]

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is [Gwenview](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gwenview/), which is a highly customizable and easy to use image viewer/image managing application.

- Crop function under "Menubar  -▸ Edit -▸ Crop" or <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>
- Also supports simple image manipulations: rotate, mirror, flip, and resize, basic file management actions such as copy, move, delete and others.
- It is a Lightwave Application (with MB) and can be extended using KIPI plugins.

[image]

---

[Gthumb](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gthumb/) - View and organize your images, also allows easy **editing** and **cropping** of images.

> gThumb is an advanced image viewer and browser. It has many useful features, such as filesystem browsing, slide show, image catalogs, web album creation, camera import, image CD burning, batch file operations and quick image editing features like transformation and color manipulation.
>
> It's designed for GNOME 2 desktop environment and uses its platform. For camera import feature, the gPhoto2 library is used.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I do a little research about the software for my problem, and I found [GIMP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp/) is best for image editing and crop selctions or windows and save or edit the image in any format.