# Program like Windows Paint for cutting and copy editting

Tags: 14.04, image-editor

I tried Pinta image editor but I can't make cut to images or copy small peices, I want a program like Paint program on windows

Comment: Err... Pinta is is far more powerful than Paint. It is closer to Paint.Net though has less functional.

Comment: This one might be of help as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/447948/crop-tool-with-high-resolution/447992#447992

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For cut a image you need to have a application with cropping ability. So it seems **GIMP Image Editor** would be helpful.

[image: Install via the software center]

Or

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) or [Shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell) - its very simple (resize and more).